# Axios request returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I have made a custom hook for fetching and I'm trying to use that hook and filter some stuff from it using my params. But the fetch returns undefined firstly which actually breaks my code.

*Custom Hook code*

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState('')


    const getData = () => {
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            axios.get(url)
                .then(response => {
                    setData(response.data);
                    setLoading(false)
                })
          } catch (error) {
            setError(error)
          }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [url])

    return {loading, data, error}

}
```

*Code where I'm trying to use the fetch*

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useFetch } from '../custom_hooks/useFetch';

const PersonDetails = () => {

    const { loading, data , error } = useFetch('https://randomuser.me/api?results=20');
    const { results } = data;
    const { id } = useParams();

    const [person, setPerson] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => { 
        const newPerson = results?.find(person => parseInt(person.login.uuid) === parseInt(id))
        console.log(newPerson)
        setPerson(newPerson)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            Testing
        </div>
    )
}

export default PersonDetails
```

Comment: You need to use a `.catch()` method (as opposed to `try..catch`) if you're not using async / await syntax

Comment: Your component's `useEffect` will run as soon as the component is mounted, and only once. This will be _before_ any async requests have completed so it's not surprising that `results` is undefined

Comment: I think that the problem is that everysingle time I click on a person to see more the api gives me new users, so the logic doesnt actually work and it returns false.